# Sort articles in communities with Napili template

Tags: lightning-aura-components, knowledge, community, napili

Does anyone know if it's possible to sort articles in communities with the Napili template ? It seems they are sorted by last modified date and I would like to sort them alphabetically.

I want to make sure there is no workaround before creating my own component...

Comment: We only use that theme for Ideas but we needed to resort to a custom component. For what ever that is worth.

Comment: Hi @Lucas Ennouchi  were you able to resolve? or did you check the bellow link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the Box, not that I know of, this will either require a custom component, OR you can download a free Appexchange package, that includes a search where you can add the existing component. It will allow you to sort your object (components included) by whatever field you have available.

The search compoent (picture below) features a component editor where you can either drag and drop interface sub-components, or edit the code directly. In the example below, I went directly to the code editor and added a sort component as follows:

```
<div class="coveo-sort-section">
      <span class="CoveoSort" data-sort-criteria="relevancy" data-caption="Relevance">
      </span>
      <span class="CoveoSort" data-sort-criteria="date descending,date ascending" data-caption="Date">
      </span>
      <span class="CoveoSort" data-sort-criteria="@SfName ascending, @SfName descending" data-caption="alpha">
      </span>
    </div>
```

To sort the @sfName field Ascending and descending.

the documentation regarding the package is available [here](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/cloud/installing_the_coveo_for_salesforce_v2_application.htm)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @glls ! Indeed I've been working with Coveo in Montreal since I posted this message and it answers perfectly my problems (and far more!!)